# Cordova - ChildBrowser

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, childbrowser

I want to make social media login using cordova apps. I already tried using inappbrowser plugin, but I want the social media login to pop up in a new windows inside the app.

When using inappbrowser its just redirecting to the page in full page of the application. I hope when someone click on login with facebook or login with google, there will be pop up windows something like childbrowser that show the login page.

Maybe there is plugin namely Childbrowser but I cant use that, saying that only cordova <= 2.9 supported. but cordova now is 5.0

Answer (score 2):

I m trying to resolve a part of your problem. To install Childbrowser plugin for cordova version > 2.9, you gotta use the following command:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/ChildBrowser#f4d5ef2ed6f35da0af8a819f30edcd53e6877770
```

This is because the latest plugin.xml changes to support latest cordova versions are not available as part of the master branch. It is available in the 'three-dot-x' branch and the above command pulls the plugin from the respective branch. Tried it myself on cordova 6.1.1 and the installation was successful.Hope it helps

Comment: `:processX86DebugManifest/home/riqi/Project/gawe/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml:13:13-30 Error:
 Missing one of the key attributes 'action#name,category#name' on element intent-filter at AndroidManifest.xml:13:13-30
/home/riqi/Project/gawe/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
 Validation failed, exiting`

I got this error when build the project

Comment: @hd_riqi this seems to be a different issue. Guess the android manifest xml is corrupted. Could try removing android platform, add again and build? Also can you confirm are you able to build android platform if you remove child browser plugin?